# Preserve Line Breaks in Pandoc Markdown -> LaTeX Conversion

Tags: pandoc

I want to convert the following `*.md` converted into proper LaTeX `*.tex`.

```
Lorem *ipsum* something.
Does anyone know lorem by heart?

That would *sad* because there's always Google.
```

**Expected Behavior / Resulting LaTeX from Pandoc**

```
Lorem \emph{ipsum} something.
Does anyone know lorem by heart?

That would \emph{sad} because there's always Google.
```

**Observed Behavior / Resulting LaTeX from Pandoc**

```
Lorem \emph{ipsum} something. Does anyone know lorem by heart?

That would \emph{sad} because there's always Google.
```

Why do I **care**?
 1. I'm transitioning a bigger git repo from markdown to LaTeX, and I want a clean diff and history.
 2. I actually like my LaTeX with one sentence-per-line even though it does not matter for the typesetting.

How can I get Pandoc to do this?

Ps.: I am aware of the option `hard_line_breaks`, but that only adds `\\` between the two first lines, and does not actually preserve my line breaks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Update

Since pandoc 1.16, this is possible:

```
pandoc --wrap=preserve
```

#### Old answer

Since Pandoc converts the Markdown to an AST-like internal representation, your non-semantic linebreaks are lost. So what you're looking for is not possible without some custom scripting (like using `--no-wrap` and then processing the output by inserting a line-break wherever there is a dot followed by a space).

However, you can use the `--columns NUMBER` options to specify the number of characters on each line. So you won't have a sentence per line, but NUMBER of characters per line.

Comment: thanks a bunch – I see that that makes sense in terms of what Pandoc is supposed to do.
I ended up having to manually reformat it; last time I'm changing markup mid-project :)

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 9):

A much simpler solution would be to add two spaces after "...something.". This will add a manual line break (the method is mentioned in the Pandoc Manual).

Comment: Thanks @René I understand that possibility.
The point here was to figure out a way to convert the `*.md` into `*.tex*` with minimal diff pollution.
I guess adding two spaces might have added such spurious diffs.

Anyway, I understand what @mb21 wrote earlier – linebreaks in tex are non-semantic, so they *must be lost* on Pandoc conversion.

I was just *using it wrong*.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer since it provides a solution and it is the one with the least overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out another way to address this problem – which is to *not* change the original `*.md`s (under version control), but to simply read them in and to have them "pandoced" when building the PDF.

Here's how:

Some `markdown.md` in project root:

```
Happy one-sentence-per-line **markdown** stuff.
And another line – makes for clear git diffs!
```

And some `latexify.tex` in project root:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\immediate\write18{pandoc markdown.md -t latex -o tmp.tex}
\input{tmp.tex}

\end{document}
```

Works just dandy if you have some markdown components in a latex project, e.g. github READMEs or sth.

Requires no special package, but compilation with `shell-escape` enabled.