# Line break in R Markdown documents without two spaces

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to use R Markdown documents for report writing in a way I used Word before for a couple of months. While RStudio/Markdown is generally great, there is one thing that keeps embarrassing me: the need to input two spaces to force a line break. My whole life related to writing on the computer screen is a life when pressing *Enter* means breaking the line. Moreover,  I see in the editor that line is broken and new paragraph starts, but after the compilation of Rmd-file I see a wall of text, without line breaks, and have to go back and check  whether all line endings have two spaces on their end. It is awful. I understand that maybe I need to develop a habit to input two spaces (which does not seem intuitive), but it is hard.

Is there a way to enforce Markdown parser in RStudio count end of the line in Rmd document as a line break, so I can avoid entering two spaces to force a line break? Maybe, there are workarounds, like RStudio addins or something else? I have searched these on the Internet but has not found any.

Comment: if your output file is a .docx file you can maybe use a double Enter as if you wanted to start a new paragraph. You can then provide a Word template file for your R markdown script (as in https://vimeo.com/110804387) in which you set no spaces between paragraphs.

Comment: Which R Markdown output format are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan PDF and Word. Currently Word. Any ideas, aside from using double Enter?

Comment: You might try setting `pandoc_args` to `--wrap=preserve`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066621/preserve-line-breaks-in-pandoc-markdown-latex-conversion

Comment: So I ended with double Enter, as @DavidePassaretti suggested. Not very clean, but that will do.