# pandoc handling of % signs in conversion from markdown to LaTeX

Tags: latex, markdown, comments, pandoc

I have a markdown document that defines a LaTeX macro and then calls it. When
I use pandoc to convert this document to LaTeX, I don't get the result that I 
expect. The problem is related to a `%` sign (LaTeX comment sign) at the end of 
my macro definition. For example, consider this markdown file:

```
\newcommand\myMacro{Hello!}%
\myMacro
```

When I run `pandoc example.md --to latex-latex_macros`, I expect it to produce a LaTeX file
that looks just like the code block above. Instead, I get

```
\newcommand\myMacro{Hello!}

\% \myMacro
```

If I add the `hard_line_breaks` option by calling 
`pandoc example.md --to latex --from markdown-latex_macros+hard_line_breaks`, I get better
output, but still not what I expect:

```
\newcommand\myMacro{Hello!}

\%\\
\myMacro
```

(Using `--wrap=preserve` produces a similar result.) I am using pandoc 2.9.2,
and I get the same result on Ubuntu and on Windows. I've experimented with
other pandoc options, and they don't seem to help. In particular, I've used
the `eol` pandoc option; it doesn't make a difference, which leads me to think
that this problem isn't due line breaks being LF or CRLF.

Why is pandoc parsing my .md file in this way? And what can I do to get it to 
produce a LaTeX file that looks like the first code block in this post? I've 
read SO posts, the pandoc user guide, and issues on the pandoc Github site.
Some of them are related: for example, [this Github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3867) and 
[Preserve Line Breaks in Pandoc Markdown -> LaTeX Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066621/). But I can't see that any of them 
speak directly to this problem.

Comment: maybe use ```{=latex}... https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute

Comment: Thank you, @mb21. Yes, that works nicely. But my ultimate hope is to write an R Markdown file, not just a markdown file, that will be converted into LaTeX as I would like. And I don't see a way to include generic raw attributes in R Markdown files -- do you? (The issue also comes up in the last paragraph of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640002/).) / I've focused here on pandoc because the problem with the R Markdown -> LaTeX conversion seems to lie with pandoc, but perhaps I should write a separate post about using generic raw attributes in R Markdown files.

Comment: AFAIK RMarkdown is using pandoc under the hood, so it should work? Maybe check that the pandoc version it's using is new enough..

Comment: Thank you -- it does indeed work. The problem was that, in an R Markdown document, I wanted to create an R code chunk that had, within it, a LaTeX code block that used the "latex" generic raw attribute. I thought that there wasn't a way to do this. But there is: just wrap the string that specifies the LaTeX macro in the `knitr::raw_latex()` function. For example, `knitr::raw_latex(c("\newcommand\myMacro{Hello!}%", "\myMacro"))` will work.